# VScode上でlatexのsynctexが使えません

Tags: vscode, latex

現在[こちらの記事](https://qiita.com/sahukita/items/85939554298f95c8c0a7#%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89)に沿って、VScode内でlatexの環境構築を行っています。PDFを出力してtex文の右側のタブに表示させるまではうまくいったのですが、PDF内の文章からctrl+クリックをしてもlatexの文に飛ぶことができません。どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。特にエラー文も出ないです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。"*.synctex.gz"が削除されて，synctex が効かなくなっていました。